# FBXのLightのポジションを取得したいのですが…

Tags: c++, visual-studio

3dsMax2015で作成したデータのライトを取得してプログラムで表示したいのですが、

Autodeskのヘルプを見てもアロー演算子を使っても位置情報がどこに入っているのかがわかりません…

誰か是非、どこに位置情報が格納されているのか教えてください！

ライトはポイントライトです。
開発ソフトはVisual Studio 2010で、
C++を使用しています。

Comment: ここは開発者向けのサイトですので、具体的なコード例やサンプルがあるといいですよ。